# Depth of ideals in a commutative ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

Let $I,J\subset S=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be two monomial ideals and $k$ a field. If every regular element on $S/J$ is also a regular element on $S/I$ is it true that $\operatorname{depth}_S S/I\ge \operatorname{depth}_S S/J$ ?

Comment: Is it obvious that $\alpha$ is a well-defined element of $S/I$?

Comment: Consider char k = 0, and $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ the polynomial ring. I'm not sure I understand your question Matt.

Comment: Also posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135889/depth-of-ideals-in-a-commutative-ring

Comment: What is the problem if it is posted on both forums?

Comment: One problem is that the question may end up answered on one side and not on the other, forever lingering... :-/